# Add Button Get started with Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, botframework, bots, messenger

I can not add the "Get Started" to all users, when I execute the command below updates only to my facebook user, how do I make it available to all users who try to talk to my bot?

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @facebook.json "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<TOKEN>"
```

file facebook.json

```
{
  "persistent_menu":[
    {
      "locale":"default",
      "composer_input_disabled": true,
      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "title":"My Account",
          "type":"nested",
          "call_to_actions":[
            {
              "title":"Pay Bill",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"PAYBILL_PAYLOAD"
            },
            {
              "type":"web_url",
              "title":"Latest News",
              "url":"https://www.messenger.com/",
              "webview_height_ratio":"full"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is your Facebook app in development mode or published for all users?  If it's in development mode, it'll only be visible to users set in roles in the app itself (Administrators/Developers/Testers).

Comment: I understood, thank you very much for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

To add the **GET STARTED** button you need to **POST** to the following:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=**{INSERT YOUR ACCESS TOKEN HERE}**

With the below body:

```
{
  "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
  "thread_state":"new_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "payload":"GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD"
    }
  ]
}
```

What you were trying to do with your call is adding a **Persistent Menu** which does not work if you don't have a **GET STARTED** button first